# Drupal 7 theming - render only content in a page

Tags: drupal-7, themes, drupal-views

I'd like to create a view with views module. The view will be at the path /myview.

Then, I want to render only view content when user in on /myview and not all the page page.

Comment: Can't figure out what you're trying to do?! Could you explain this a bit better ?!

Comment: Might have better luck on the Drupal stack  http://drupal.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I want to create a new panel or a new view. Then I want user load /drupal/myview_path and load only page content withoud sidebar, blocks, menu and html headers.

Because I need to export dynamically page html. Not all the drupal page.